# Visual Studios installation through WINE

Tags: wine

Is it possible to install Visual Studios (2008/2010) with WINE ? I have used Mono, not very happy with it, is a Visual Studio installation possible in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to install it via WINE, but only Visual Studios version 6 with average rating on WINE (Silver), another version is not recommended to install. Please check on [their object manager](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892).

Comment: Ver 6 is like stone age ! :-(